# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer[-fpermissive] in C++ code

Tags: c++, pointers

There is a problem with my code. It always return an error ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer[-fpermissive]. Can you help me see what is the problem here and how to solve it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char x;
int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the citation machine. What do you want to cite?" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == "book")
    {
        cout << "What is the name of the book?";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're comparing a char with a string, what do you want to do?

Comment: The error message is correct, and telling you what the problem is.

Comment: you are comparing a `char` (x) with an array of char, that array of char is decayed to a pointer, that is your problem.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more
specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to
incorporate the exact error text (preferably using
copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 12):

```
#include <iostream>
```

`char` is not a string, it is a character, means an integer (signed between -128 and 127 on most compiler implementations)

If you change the type of `x` to `string` it will do what you want

You had a raw C comparison `char` vs `char *` which explains the error message

By turning the `char` into a `string` you activate the `string::operator==` which accepts `char *` as a convenience and performs a string comparison, which is intuitively what you want to do.

My advice is: keep going with C++ and never use `char *`, `malloc` or all that C stuff likely to fail, stick to `std::string`, and use `std::string::c_str()` to get the string contents as `const char *` for use with C primitives if needed.
A positive side-effect is that it will avoid the trap of comparing 2 `char *` types with `==` operator, which compare pointers and not values.

```
using namespace std;
string x;
int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the citation machine. What do you want to cite?" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == "book")
    {
        cout << "What is the name of the book?";
    }
}
```

Comment: even with char is a signed char in 8 bit per char system, if that system doesn't use 2 complement, signed char may not in range [-128, 127]

Comment: I have updated my post. It was extra info, not really necessary for the comprehension of the error message but hey I'm a generous guy. Thanks.